# How to make a shell script take an argument passed in the command line?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a shell script (count_reviews.sh) that contains the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
grep -c "Author" "#1"
```

I have tried using "$1" as I found that this takes the first argument in the command line but I still get the error mentioned below. I have also used chmod +x to make my file executable.

The script counts the number of times "Author" appears in the file. I am required to be able to make the command line take an input of `"% ./count_reviews.sh hotel_72572.dat"` where `hotel_72572.dat` is an example file name. The number of times author appears will then be printed out underneath. When I do this however, I am getting an error `-bash: fg: %: no such job`. What is causing this and how do I fix it? My `count_reviews.sh` file is in the same directory as all of my hotel data files if that matters.

Comment: The `%` is a common default prompt used in the c-shell (csh), I'm wondering if that's where it came from (others, like bash, use `$` for ordinary users, `#` for root).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should indeed use `$1`, but when you try to run your script just use `./your_script.sh your_argument` don't add the `%` in the beginning.

Comment: But my specification requires it to be there? What function does it hold?

Comment: The `%` is used in job control : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_control_%28Unix%29#Commands. That's why you get the `fg: no current job` error.

Comment: and how could I alter this to make it so that it checks for "Author" in all files in a directory?

Comment: What do you mean by that ? Do you want grep to recursively check every file in a given directory ? If so, just add the argument `-r` to the grep command.

Comment: In place of the -c I assume?

Comment: No you can use both of them, like this `grep -cr "Author" $1`.